# Unrecognized artifact type: orbit, will not add this as a dependency in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, configuration, vaadin

I'm configuring an existing project build in Vaadin to Intellij but during IVY Resolve for this project module, following error happens:

```
org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.transaction;1.1.1.v201105210645:  Unrecognized artifact type: orbit, will not add this as a dependency in IntelliJ.
org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.servlet;3.0.0.v201112011016:  Unrecognized artifact type: orbit, will not add this as a dependency in IntelliJ.
org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.mail.glassfish;1.4.1.v201005082020:   Unrecognized artifact type: orbit, will not add this as a dependency in IntelliJ.
org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.activation;1.1.0.v201105071233:   Unrecognized artifact type: orbit, will not add this as a dependency in IntelliJ.
org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.annotation;1.1.0.v201108011116:   Unrecognized artifact type: orbit, will not add this as a dependency in IntelliJ.
org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#org.objectweb.asm;3.1.0.v200803061910:  Unrecognized artifact type: orbit, will not add this as a dependency in IntelliJ.
```

How could this one be fixed?

For more detail reference here is `ivysetting` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="default" />
    <resolvers>
        <chain name="default">
            <!-- Public Maven repository -->
            <ibiblio name="public" m2compatible="true" />

            <!-- Vaadin Add-on repository -->
            <ibiblio name="vaadin-addons" usepoms="true" m2compatible="true"
                root="http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons" />

            <!-- Vaadin snapshots repository -->
            <ibiblio name="vaadin-snapshots" usepoms="true" m2compatible="true"
                root="https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots" />
            <!-- Repository used for Vaadin modified smartsprites library -->
            <dual name="custom-smartsprites">
                <filesystem name="smartsprites-ivy">
                    <ivy pattern="${basedir}/ivymodule/[module]-ivy-[revision].xml" />
                </filesystem>
                <url name="smartsprites-artifact">
                    <artifact
                        pattern="http://dev.vaadin.com/svn/versions/6.8/build/smartsprites/lib/[artifact](-[revision]).[ext]" />
                </url>
            </dual>
        </chain>
    </resolvers>
    <modules>
        <!-- Vaadin patched SmartSprites -->
        <module organisation="com.carrotsearch" name="smartsprites"
            revision="0.2.3-itmill" resolver="custom-smartsprites" />
    </modules>
</ivysettings>
```

Comment: Probably more details are needed to be able to solve this problem from here. E.g. how your project is configured, any build tools like maven or gradle are in use? And what is `orbit`?

Comment: No build tools are not in use, to resolve dependencies ivy is used. Editing the question to put more details.

Comment: Tried configuring it in `Settings > Other Settings > IvyIDEA`, found it here: https://github.com/guymahieu/ivyidea/issues/143 (I've might be asking silly questions, but I've never used ivy)

Comment: See https://github.com/guymahieu/ivyidea/issues/143#issuecomment-165035578